# $_SESSION value not getting updated

Tags: php, session

I have two functions in PHP - one to generate a token and store it in `$_SESSION`:

```
public static function generateToken($sessionTokenName = null)
{
    $token = SomeTokenGenerationCode();
    if (! $sessionTokenName) {
        $sessionTokenName = 'csrfToken';
    }
    $_SESSION['csrf'][$sessionTokenName] = $token;
    $_SESSION['csrf']['timestamp'] = time();
    Log::error(__METHOD__, ['timestamp' => $_SESSION['csrf']['timestamp']]);
    Log::error(__METHOD__, ['token' => $_SESSION['csrf'][$sessionTokenName]]);
    Log::error(__METHOD__, ['token_g' => $token]);
    Log::error(__METHOD__, ['seesion token name' => $sessionTokenName]);

    return $token;
}
```

The other function is to verify this token:

```
   public static function verifyToken($token, $sessionTokenName = null)
    {
            Log::error(__METHOD__, ['timestamp' => $_SESSION['csrf']['timestamp']]);
            Log::error(__METHOD__, ['token' => $_SESSION['csrf']]);
            Log::error(__METHOD__, ['token_g' => $token]);
            Log::error(__METHOD__, ['seesion token name' => $sessionTokenName]);

            if (! $sessionTokenName) {
            $sessionTokenName = 'csrfToken';
        }
        if (!array_key_exists($sessionTokenName, $_SESSION['csrf'])) {
            return false;
        }
        $sessionToken = $_SESSION['csrf'][$sessionTokenName];

        Log::error(__METHOD__, ['token_seesion' => $_SESSION['csrf'][$sessionTokenName]]);
        Log::error(__METHOD__, ['token_for_verify' => $token]);


        if (empty($token) || $token !== $sessionToken) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Some times this works, but some times - I get this:

```
[2024-03-20 14:15:00] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::generateToken {"timestamp":1710958500}
[2024-03-20 14:15:00] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::generateToken {"token":"34ufit971v0gw0wo"}
[2024-03-20 14:15:00] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::generateToken {"token_g":"34ufit971v0gw0wo"}
[2024-03-20 14:15:00] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::generateToken {"seesion token name":"payments-create"}
[2024-03-20 14:15:05] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::verifyToken {"timestamp":1710958500}
[2024-03-20 14:15:05] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::verifyToken {"token":{"login":"i9345ku3lxk4k040","payments-create":"34ufit971v0gw0wo","timestamp":1710958500}}
[2024-03-20 14:15:05] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::verifyToken {"token_g":"34ufit971v0gw0wo"}
[2024-03-20 14:15:05] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::verifyToken {"seesion token name":"payments-create"}
[2024-03-20 14:15:05] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::verifyToken {"token_seesion":"34ufit971v0gw0wo"}
[2024-03-20 14:15:05] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::verifyToken {"token_for_verify":"34ufit971v0gw0wo"}

[2024-03-20 14:15:27] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::generateToken {"timestamp":1710958527}
[2024-03-20 14:15:27] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::generateToken {"token":"ssa6v2j2x340ss00"}
[2024-03-20 14:15:27] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::generateToken {"token_g":"ssa6v2j2x340ss00"}
[2024-03-20 14:15:27] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::generateToken {"seesion token name":"payments-create"}
[2024-03-20 14:15:34] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::verifyToken {"timestamp":1710958500}
[2024-03-20 14:15:34] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::verifyToken {"token":{"login":"i9345ku3lxk4k040","payments-create":"34ufit971v0gw0wo","timestamp":1710958500}}
[2024-03-20 14:15:34] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::verifyToken {"token_g":"ssa6v2j2x340ss00"}
[2024-03-20 14:15:34] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::verifyToken {"seesion token name":"payments-create"}
[2024-03-20 14:15:34] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::verifyToken {"token_seesion":"34ufit971v0gw0wo"}
[2024-03-20 14:15:34] local.ERROR: App\Util\CsrfTokenUtil::verifyToken {"token_for_verify":"ssa6v2j2x340ss00"}
```

As you can see - in the 2nd time - the old token is being compared with the new token. The `$_SESSION` wasn't updated on the second call.

Why does this happen? how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure this is being done on the same session?

Comment: In your debug log print the sessionID so you can confirm the session is the same

Comment: Thanks, I'll try - it's a page load and than submitting. it works half of the time, and if I add sleep after token generation - it works all the time...